# Power series with array input

Tags: matlab, math, power-series

I want to do the following in Matlab:

[image: equation]

`i` is the imaginary unit

`r` is a vector of length `n`: `[r(1),...,r(n)]`

phi is a 1x300 double, i.e. `[phi(1),...,phi(300)]`

```
sum(r(1:n).*(1i.^(1:n))./factorial(1:n))
```

This would work if there was no phi. But how can I implement the phi here?

```
sum(r(1:n).*((phi*1i).^(1:n))./factorial(1:n))
```

results in:

> Matrix dimensions must agree.

The expected output is the same size as `phi`. This code would achieve what I want but I want `n` to be dynamic so the looping is not feasible:

```
if n==1
    R = r(1) * ( i * phi )
elseif n==2
    R = r(1) * ( i * phi ) + r(2) * ( i * phi ).^2 / 2;
elseif n==3
    R = r(1) * ( i * phi ) + r(2) * ( i * phi ).^2 / 2 + r(3) * ( i * phi ).^3 / 6;
...
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is the size of `n`? If it isn't 300, then there is a mismatch between `r` and `phi`. I also notice that `phi` is not indexed in your equation, so is `phi ` a constant or a vector?

Comment: @Lucas Yes I mistakenly wrote c instead of r. I corrected it. n can be arbitrary (n is given as an input for my function). I understand that my code does not work because the size of n isn't 300 - I'm looking for another way so that the sum can be computed for arbitary n (the size of phi is 300 and it is fixed, but n can vary)

Comment: the dot-product between `r` and `phi` will only work if they are the same size. So it won't work for arbitrary `n`.

Comment: Please include a [mcve], say for `n=3`. How do you expect the terms of `phi` to be collected? Do you expect a 300-element output, with one sum per value of `phi`? Please also include your MATLAB version, it looks like you're straying towards requiring implicit expansion which is version-specific (although now not all that new)

Comment: @Wolfie I added it above. Yes I expect a 300 element output (the code I added above has a 1x300 double as output. That's exactly what I want, but I want to get rid of all the if's and instead program it as sum from 1 going to n - so that I dont have to check if n==1, if n==2 and so on)

I use MATLAB R2021b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transpose `phi`, and then transpose your result back at the end, this looks something like

```
s = sum(r(1:n).*((phi.'*1i).^(1:n))./factorial(1:n),2).'
```

note the `.'` after `phi` and at the end to transpose. I've also included `,2` in the sum to sum along the 2nd dimension.

This relies on [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) to create an intermediate matrix.

i.e. the operations between `phi.'` (a column array) and your row arrays (`r(1:n)`, `(1:n)`, and `factorial(1:n)`) are evaluated element-wise, making a matrix which is `300 x n`. Then we sum in the 2nd dimension (`sum(__,2)`) to get a `300x1` output, which is finally transposed back to a `1x300` output to match your original `phi`.

Answer (score -1):

Given your example, you could do

```
ind_end = min(n, length(phi))
sum(r(1:ind_end).*((phi(1:ind_end)*1i).^(1:ind_end))./factorial(1:ind_end))
```

This works for any `n` by avoiding the indexing to go beyond the length of `phi`.

Comment: This avoids throwing an error but also does not give the correct result I think, the desired output would compute the series for each value of `phi`, outputting something the same size as `phi`, which this does not do